# Get values in array of objects Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of objects in the telescope as follows. I need to get only the number and each number is placed in a numerical variable

```
"[[{"num":333}],[{"num":433}],[{"num":3033}],[{"num":533}],[{"num":514}],[{"num":1440}]]"
```

Ex

```
$var1 = 333
$var2 = 433
```

In the telescope appears exactly like this

```
"[[{"num":333}],[{"num":433}],[{"num":3033}],[{"num":533}],[{"num":514}],[{"num":1440}]]"
```

Comment: Is that a php array where each element is an array containing one object with a property `num` with a numeric value?

Comment: Where are you reading that: on client (i.e. in browser)?

Comment: It seems JSON string. Why not you trying JSON decode and the loop and use the values.

Comment: `$res='[[{"num":333}],[{"num":433}],[{"num":3033}],[{"num":533}],[{"num":514}],[{"num":1440}]]'; print_r(json_decode($res, 1));`

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways you could do it.

```
$decoded = json_decode("[[{"num":333}],[{"num":433}],[{"num":3033}],[{"num":533}],[{"num":514}],[{"num":1440}]]");

$vars = [];
foreach ($decoded as $i => $v) {
    $vars["var{$i + 1}"] = $v[0]["num"];
}

extract($vars);
```

The result will be:

```
$var1 = 333;
$var2 = 433;
...
```

The [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function extracts the keys of the associative array and registers them as variables in the variable table while assigning the corresponding value to them.